# How can I draw a rounded rectangle Label or View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to draw a rounded rectangle bar in my iOS application, but without using a background image. Is there any way to make a rounded rectangle view or label?

Comment: hey first Ravi has answered your question.check it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In addition to the other answer(s), don't forget to set the `masksToBounds` property.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

label.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I don't know whether masksToBounds defaults to YES, but I didn't set it and I've still got the rounded corners.

Comment: The default is `NO`. Maybe it was set somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative if you're using the UI designer (Storyboard or nib file) you can set a User Defined Runtime Attribute.

Click on the view you want to have rounded corners, click Show the Identity Inspector (3rd tab, top right).
Then click the + in User Defined Runtime Attributes and enter the following:

```
Key Path: layer.cornerRadius
Type: Number
Value: whatever number, e.g. 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Add Quartz core Framework ..

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then Set corner radius,

```
yourView_LabelName.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be useful for you.
Step1 :add the quartzcore framework to your project frameworks.
In which file you want to write this code there, you have to use this.

```
        #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 50, 30)];
        myLabel.text = @"text";
        myLabel.layer.cornerRadius =8.0;
        [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```